# v-if doesn't dynamically change value

Tags: vue.js

I'm working in a Vue.js and I have :

```
 <span v-if="!change[product.id]['name']" v-on:click="show(product.id, 'name')" style="cursor:pointer">
    {{{ product.name }}}
</span>

<span v-if="change[product.id]['name']">
    okays
</span>
```

I initialise my 'change' with that :

```
this.$set('products', response.data.products)
self.productsLoading=false
let array = []
array['name'] = false
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.products.length; i++) {
  self.change[response.data.products[i].id] = array;
}
console.log(self.change)
```

So my `console.log` show me the array I want to have so so far so good.

And my show function :

```
show(id, field){
    let array = this.change
    array[id][field] = true
    this.$set('change',array)
    console.log(this.change)
},
```

Once more, my `console.log` is still good when i click on the product.name but I still see the product.name instead of "okays"

Data definition :

```
data() {
        return {
            products: [],
            change: []
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your `data` definition?

Comment: @Nora it's done

Comment: [Here](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn’t-the-DOM-updating) is an explanation of how to fix the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line might be a problem:

```
let array = []
array['name'] = false
```

Use `{}` instead of `[]` if you need to use `array` variable as dictionary (object).